# How to change meta content attribute and update document mode dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

Is it possible to change a meta tag like the following with jQuery:

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8'/>
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9'/> ... or IE=10
```

Doing so does not seem to update the document mode. Do I need to refresh something?

Why? Using Bootstrap and it appears that IE8 standards document mode does not (fully?) support css media queries.. among other things. I am stuck with a page at the moment that has content='IE=8' in it even though we're using IE9.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can, but it is not going to do any good. It will be too late to change that.

Comment: @SidM Searched and couldn't find it-thanks.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, that's what I thought, just hoped I was overlooking something..

Comment: IE 8 does not support media queries.  http://caniuse.com/#search=media  You have to use a polyfill to  make them work.   https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: if you could, i'd give you a checkmark, that seems like a somewhat reasonable solution for a crappy situation.